# Is it possible to 'git pull' only the next commit?

Tags: git, git-pull

I understand `git pull` will update the working branch to the tip of a remote branch that it tracks.  So let's say if I do `git pull`, it will pull in all the latest changes.  In my case, it will pull in 5 changes on top of my tree.

Is there a way to `git pull` only the next change?  i.e., if `git pull` would put change 03, 04, 05, 06 and 07 on top of my tree, how do I pull only change 03?  At the time of this command I do not know the commit ID of the next change it would pull in.

The tip of my tree is completely unaltered and will not have any merge conflicts and such.

Comment: Man, all these silly compound commands in Git ;-)

Answer (score 16):

Perhaps something like this?

```
git fetch
git merge <commit to merge>
```

To find the ID of the commit you want to merge, look it up in gitk after running the fetch.

Comment: As I said in the question, "At the time of this command I do not know the commit ID of the next change it would pull in."

Comment: Adam: You do git fetch and then look in gitk to find the commit ID.

Comment: This question was maybe asked for situations like searching for the commit which introduced a bug. 
By pulling commits one by one, it would be possible to quickly find a searched commit (pull commit 03 + check, pull commit 04 + check...).
Pasting commit IDs from gitk or just 'git log' is a working solution, but will not be as handy as just pulling commits one by one.

Answer (score 1):

You can. Quite simple:

```
git fetch
git log --oneline --decorate --graph --all
git merge <some-commit-id>
#Repeat last line as often as you wish
#to incorporate upstream changes piecemeal.
```

The combination of flags to `git log` is really useful to get a quick overview of what has happened, so much so that I always have a shell alias defined to use this precise combination:

```
alias gitlog='git log --oneline --decorate --graph'
```

With that alias, the above sequence becomes

```
git fetch
gitlog --all
git merge ...
...
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible in theory. `git status` shows there are 8 commits to pull, if a script could parse out the "8" and take an input (defaulting to 1) for the number of next commits you want. You could run `git-pull-next 2` and it could do this:

1. In some way, check how many new commits there are (git status works)
2. Set to variable `newCommits`
3. Also set variable, `pullNextNCommits`, equal to cli input, defaults to 1
4. Run git pull
5. Run git log
6. Grab the commit hash that is `newCommits` ago, minus `pullNextNCommits`
7. Store variable `current_git_branch` as result of `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`
8. Run `git checkout <hash>`
9. delete current_git_branch locally
10. `git checkout -b current_git_branch`

TADA! Not impossible! Just have to write this script...

This answer is a community wiki, feel free to flesh out the psuedocode more

There's probably a better way to do this - since a git pull merge could have issues, it'd be better to take inspiration from the first answer here. But somehow, programmatically find the next commit hash.